# Machine Learning algorithm for predicting a user's rating on an item?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to build an **supervised learning algorithm** that deals with the regression problem of **predicting a user's rating** of a new incoming item **based on the user's previous ratings** on items. The ratings will be in the range of 1 - 5 (1 = best, 5 = worst).

Features a item will probably have:

- **author (nominal)**
- **release channel (nominal, can be empty)**
- **length in minutes** (most likely something between 2 and 15, but can be higher)
- **release year (nominal)**

The outcome of the algorithm should be a rating for an previously unrated item. (**Should be a decimal value** - for ordering the predictions, like **something between 1.0 and 5.0, or normalized 0.0 to 1.0**)

What type of algorithm would suit this prediction problem best and how would i implement it?

Comment: This is a broad question, since there are many different algorithms for [recommendation systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system) that may be suitable. That Wikipedia article distinguishes between collaborative filtering and content-based filtering; you should consider which of those makes more sense for your application.

Comment: It will definitely be a content-based recommender. My particular question would be which algorithm to choose for building a user profile.

Comment: I see you [asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63638621/781723), and you got some suggestions there, but that doesn't appear to be reflected here.  Please revise your post based on the feedback you've already received.  In particular, tell us what your requirements are, what approaches you've already considered, and why you've rejected them.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking and to summarize what you've found so far.

Comment: What ML algorithm will perform best is very domain-specific and often cannot be known in advance; we often need to try out many approaches and see how well they work.  I would suggest what would be most constructive would be to try to some simple methods and see how well they work.  That might help you narrow down your question.